# Taking derivative under integral

Tags: integration, partial-derivative

I am reading a paper, the author takes the derivative of the following equation with respect to $t$:
$$ q(t) = \int_t^\infty e^{-r(s-t)}c(s)e^{-\delta(s-t)}ds $$

I have the answer, the integral sign disappears, but I was hoping someone would explain the intermediate points leading up to the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If *the integral sign disappears*, then there must be relations that are not shown. Assuming that $r,\delta$ are constant, you compute from 
$$ q(t) = \int_t^\infty e^{-r(s-t)}c(s)e^{-\delta(s-t)}ds = \int_t^\infty e^{-(r+\delta)(s-t)}c(s) ds $$
with the [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Formal_statement) the derivative as

$$q'(t) = \int_t^\infty (r+\delta)e^{-(r+\delta)(s-t)}c(s)ds - c(t)$$

Comment: Many thanks! I got it now. The solution, ignoring $t$, shown in the paper, is $$\dot {q} = q(r+\sigma) - c$$ Your solution is correct as $(r+\delta)$ is a constant so it will be outside the integral sign and the rest under the integral sign is $q$. I just did not get it right on my own. Thanks!

Comment: This seems just sloppy notation of my answer, i.e. an abridged form without the argument $t$  and the integral written as $q(t)$
$$q'(t) = (r+\delta)q(t) - c(t)$$ The given form is misleading for me, I would read it as if $r+\delta$ is the argument of $q()$